Best Practices for Exposing read-only data in a class
I'm working on a C++ project where I need to expose some data (specifically a std::vector ) from a class to users of the class. The key requirement is that I want the data to be read-only, and also want to ensure that the elements within the container are read-only aswell. I want to avoid unnecessary copying for performance reasons.
Here are some approaches I've considered:
Returning a const std::vector<int>& — This makes the container read-only, but the elements can still be modified if they're not const.
Using std::span — Provides a read-only view without copying, but I'm not sure if it's the best fit for my use case.
I'm curious to hear from others:What are the best practices you've found for exposing read-only data in C++?

Why don't you think std::span fits your use case?  It sounds like its exactly what you want

You could implement a get function but not the set function.  Have the get function return a constant reference or a copy of the member.

"Returning a const std::vector<int>& — This makes the container read-only, but the elements can still be modified if they're not const" - no, constness of std::vector is deep, you cannot modify an element of const std::vector (even through a reference).

For "leaf" value types (int, std::string), I expose read only data by passing it back by value.   For heavier weight types a const&; or container types, I return a const iterator or a std::pair of const iterators.  (I'm on C++17.  If I was on C++20, I'd also consider returning a "fat pointer" (std::span) to const.)

"but the elements can still be modified if they're not const" Issue only happens with pointers which don't propagate const, and there is std::experimental::propagate_const for that.

Both returning const std::vector<int>& or std::span<const int> are fine

std::span<const int> is good enough. You can later limit the range of accessible elements(drop elements from both ends) if needed. But, you must also ensure that any reference/view into a container doesn't live longer than original object.

I have an idea that making your read-only data as private fields of your classes, and exposing APIs to provide const random access iterators.
For example:
class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator Begin() const
    {
        return data_.cbegin();
    }

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator End() const
    {
        return data_.cend();
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> data_;
};


nice comments, update it
